# R File Name Truncate

Tags: r, filenames, truncate

We have a bunch of file names of the form:

```
filename1(412)(4141567).csv, filename2(4214985).csv, filename3(34543).csv, filename4(3456984).csv, filename5(34582).csv, filename6(jrh)(234145).csv
```

What we are looking to do is truncate the file names so that we are left with only

```
filename1(412),filename2,filename3,...,filename6(jrh).
```

i.e. to cut off the end of the name up until the last "(" bracket.

We cannot use substring as each of the file names are not exactly the same length. Also the following code I found:

```
sub("(.*?)[(].*", "\\1", files)
```

does not work either as some file names have two sets of brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last regex you posted is pretty close, try this:

```
sub('(.*)\\(.*', '\\1', files)
```

Comment: Thank you for all responses. This one was the simplest for what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tools::file_path_sans_ext` which runs (which only removes the file extension):

```
sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", x)
```

*EDIT*:

I didn't see that you want to remove the last `(...)`, too:

```
f <- c("filename1(412)(4141567).csv", "filename2(4214985).csv", "filename3(34543).csv", "filename4(3456984).csv", "filename5(34582).csv", "filename6(jrh)(234145).csv")

sub("([^.]+)\\([^)]*\\)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", f)
#[1] "filename1(412)" "filename2"      "filename3"      "filename4"      "filename5"      "filename6(jrh)"
```